# Passing dataProvider parameter inside testng method

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, pom.xml

I have two @DataProviders:

```
@DataProvider(name = "smallNumbers")
@DataProvider(name = "bigNumbers")
```

Variables in pom.xml

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
<dataP>${dataProvider}</dataP>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Accesing parameter:

```
String sizeNumbers = System.getProperty("dataP");
```

And my test:

```
@Test(dataProvider=sizeNumbers)
```

dataProvider in test method have to be:
a constant expression 
Any idea how to pass variable inside @Test(dataProvider= ?

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this. It is only possible to pass dataprovider directly to method.
Why you choose that way to inject data from dataprovider? Show a bit more about your code architecture cause that's look strange.

**EDIT:**

You can check this way:

```
@DataProvider(name = "dp")
public static Object[][] dataInject(){
  return new Object[][]{
            {sizeNumbers}
  };
}
```

And inside "dp" you can also make some validation for ex. "isNull" etc.

Then in test

```
@Test(dataProvider = "dp", dataProviderClass = Xyz.class)
public void testFirst(String input){
//...
}
```

Comment: Im looking for a way to set dataProvider depending on parameter passed from jenkins(thats a must); jenkins(choose parameter size) > pass to pom.xml maven > parameter smallNumbers > dataProvider smallNumbers

Comment: Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: do you have any possibilities to redirect output from jenkins [test data] to other xml?